# Download files with one http request and no zipping

Tags: javascript, iphone, http, sockets

I need to download many photos and videos from the server. I am using cocoaasyncsocket library, and I could accomplish this by zipping all the contents and download the zipped file with one button click.

But the problem is zipping the files take a lot of time. So, is there any way where I could download all the files without zipping them.

Comment: iPhone application has many photos and videos which starts the server to share through WiFi. An html page is opened in the browser in the client side. There are options to download individual files, which works fine as every file will have a button with href set up. There is an another option to download all the images. But there can be 500 or more images(or videos). So zipping this is taking time. Won't 'tar' be similar to zip.

Comment: Try to use nsurlconnection documentation it ll use full for you.without out zipping downloading a file is waste of time and memory...so you download the file which is zip and unzip through minizip classes.

Comment: @AAAAAAAAA: But zipping also wastes the time and memory/CPU.

Comment: @AAAAAAAAA: zip can't actually further compress modern images or video, so the _compression_ portion of `zip` is actually wasting time on both server and client. It remains useful only because it is a single link to click. :)

Comment: sarnold is given good statement "single link to click", sana cant you use this..

Answer (score 1):

Sana, I was wrong, `zip` *can* be used in a stream:

```
zip -0 -r - .
```

will start recursively storing files from the current directory and send output to standard output. You can capture the standard output (see `popen(3)`) and begin sending it to clients immediately.

Comment: Thanks sarnold. I need to check this. I am slow at understanding and using linux commands.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when the creation of the zip archive took a long time but I needed to download more than one file.

The thing that saved me was 
http://pablotron.org/?cid=1568
Zip Stream is a class that creates the zip archive on the fly and while is being downloaded.

Most of the on the fly classes create the archive ( while you wait for the download to start ) and only after it is completely created, they start sending the archive to you. This class starts sending the archive as it is created, like this you will save the time that you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, does it mean that the download will become slower. And how will the response for this request be?